# I am unable to achieve click effect when hover over image

Tags: html, css

The sample div hovers fine however the background image doesn't move.
The div hovers fine but the image in the background stays at the same position.
What I am trying to achieve is when you hover over the div it moves like it clicks, but the background image in the div doesn't seems to move at all. I want the div and the background to move like real button click. 
Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/YhDXm/.

```css
.sample {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 180px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  background: url(http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2362.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 188px 188px;
}
.sample > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sample > header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.sample > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.sample > header p a {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.sample:hover {
  background-color: #f0eade;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <header>
    <p><a>
          Skyscraper
        </a>
    </p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is rather different than your question. It's not clear to me what you're after.

Comment: do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1185/ ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what i am saying is the div sample moves when hovered, but the image does not. So I want the Image to move along with the div.

Comment: @caramba thanks for the tip appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image stays still because you have `background-attachment: fixed;` enabled.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) on `background-attachment: fixed`

> This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.

Remove your `background-attachment` statement entirely and change your `background-position` to `0 0` (or top left) and then you will need to tinker the child elements appropriately.

**[Fiddle here with adjustments made.](http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1186/)**

Now that I'm done with that, some supplemental advice:

You should **most certainly not do this** using `top` or any other positional properties.  These will cause a **layout** re-calculation on every single hover event (even with `position: absolute;`) and a paint, at a minimum.  If you have a lot of stuff on that page your users may become frustrated or displeased with the stuttering on the page.

Instead, use `transform: translate(X, Y);` for a very cheap and equally effective move.  [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1187/) with this incorporated

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question, thanks everyone for the help,
This is fiddle linke:  http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1186/

```
.sample {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 180px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  background: url(http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2362.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.sample > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sample > header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.sample > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.sample > header p a {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.sample:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 180px;
}
<div class="sample">
  <header>
    <p><a>
          Skyscraper
        </a>
    </p>
  </header>
</div>
```